# How to show progress bar in a window during downloading in electron-updater

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I'm developing my app with electron and I'm using electron-updater to show a window that asks to the user if he wants download a new app version or not.
I've tried to show in a window a progress bar during the downloading like this.
[image: progress-bar]

I've tried to use progress-bar but if I install it, the electron-updater stop working. Now I can see the progress only in dev mode into the electron shell.

```
autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
    let log_message = "Scaricamento aggiornamenti in corso...  \n";
    log_message = log_message +  "Velocita\' scaricamento: " + 
        progressObj.bytesPerSecond;
    log_message = log_message + ' - Scaricati ' + progressObj.percent + '%';
    log_message = log_message + ' (' + progressObj.transferred + "/" + 
        progressObj.total + ')';
    log.log('info', log_message);
})
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking and i don't have enough reputation to add a comment...so i'll do my best)

I assume that autoUpdater is in the main process, not in a renderer. So, the first thing you need to do is get the data from the progress update to the correct renderer. You can do this using electron's `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` modules.

Once you have the data in the renderer process you need to get it to the progress bar. If you are using redux, you can call your store's dispatch(), passing a downloadProgress action to it.

In my app, which uses redux, I create a `DownloadProgress` action in the main process and send it over IPC to the renderer. I'd recommend doing the same since you'll probably want to pass `DownloadCancelled` and `DownloadComplete` actions too.

If this is not helpful, please clarify the following:

- please add the code that *doesn't* work your question -- this would help understand more precisely what you are trying to do
- is autoUpdate running in the main process, or in a renderer
- which progress bar implementation you are using (an npm package?) and how will you send data to it (directly or through a store?)